# How can I install Ubuntu 11.04 via VNC on my new PC (with no keyboard or mouse)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, installation, debian

I have downloaded the latest Ubuntu.iso and extracted it to `/tmp/ubuntu/` on my laptop. In the folder `isolinux` there is an `isolinux.cfg` file. I am trying to prepare a USB stick by modifying those files, so that when I boot from USB it opens VNC and puts a static IP of `192.168.1.125`.

How can I enable VNC and a static IP so that from my laptop I can do the installation of Ubuntu 11.04 without using a keyboard or mouse?

Example:

> http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda_Boot_Options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu's equivalent for anaconda is [kickstart](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/installation-guide/i386/automatic-install.html). This might be what you're looking for.